Flask Deprecated before_first_request
rollbar implementation
I'm following a tutorial, apperently flask deprecated before_first_request. Anyone know how I can fix this?
I tried to downgrade to flask 2.1.3 but that bring up other errors too. if anyone can help me with this, I would pretty much appreciate it.

Please provide your code in text format instead of image format.
